# Ordering record based on list field in apache ignite Sql Queries

Tags: ignite

Lets say I have an object Employee below and it is stored in ignite cache.

```
   Employee{
    int id;
    String name;
    List<Double> marksInorder;//marks for each subject in order
    //hypothetical situation, actual requirement is different
  }
```

I am using SQLQuery to fetch records from ignite cache and need to fetch top N records with maximum of marksInorder. But ignite does not support orderBy on list fields.

http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Ignite-SQL-Queries-on-Lists-fields-sorting-td14129.html#a14305

Is there a workaround for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the solution by using @QuerySqlFunction. My custom SqlFunction is converting list of doubles to maximum value in list and finally I am sorting it in descending order. Watch the output. Here it is

```
public class Student implements Serializable {
    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    private int Id;
    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    private String name;

    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    private List<Double> marks;
    //rest of POJO code

}

public class MySqlFunctions {
    @QuerySqlFunction
    public static double maxOf(List<Double> marksInorder) {
        Collections.sort(marksInorder, Collections.reverseOrder());
        return marksInorder.get(0);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml");
        CacheConfiguration<Integer, Student> config = new CacheConfiguration<>("students");
        config.setIndexedTypes(Integer.class, Student.class);
        config.setSqlFunctionClasses(MySqlFunctions.class);
        IgniteCache<Integer, Student> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(config);
        List<Double> marks1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> marks2 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> marks3 = new ArrayList<>();
        marks1.add(12.3);
        marks1.add(4.3);
        marks2.add(1.3);
        marks2.add(14.3);
        marks3.add(13.3);
        marks3.add(3.3);
        Student s1 = new Student(1, "John", marks1);
        Student s2 = new Student(2, "Dan", marks2);
        Student s3 = new Student(3, "Ron", marks3);
        cache.put(s1.getId(), s1);
        cache.put(s2.getId(), s2);
        cache.put(s3.getId(), s3);
        String sql = "select * from Student order by maxOf(marks) desc";
        SqlQuery<Integer, Student> query = new SqlQuery<>(Student.class, sql);
        List<Student> result = cache.query(query).getAll().stream().map(e -> e.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("Result : " + result);
    }


Result : [Student [Id=2, name=Dan, marks=[1.3, 14.3]], Student [Id=3, name=Ron, marks=[13.3, 3.3]], Student [Id=1, name=John, marks=[12.3, 4.3]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest workaround is to add `Double maxmark` field and configure it to be indexed.

Comment: Thanks Valentin for replying. I think I have found a solution to it. Basically we can use @QuerySqlFunction annotation to customize fields in ignite SQLQuery.
I will post it shortly here after testing